# Retrieve values from multimdimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a great difficulty. I need to retrieve [title], [url] and [abstract] values ​​from this multidimensional array.

Also, I have to store those values in mysql database.

thanks in advance!!!

```
Array
(
    [bossresponse] => Array
        (
            [responsecode] => 200
            [limitedweb] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 0
                    [count] => 20
                    [totalresults] => 972000
                    [results] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 
                                    [clickurl] => http://www.torchlake.com/
                                    [url] => http://www.torchlake.com/
                                    [dispurl] => www.torchlake.com
                                    [title] => Torch Lake, COLI Inc, Highspeed, Dial-up, Wireless ...
                                    [abstract] => Welcome to COLI Inc. Chain O' Lake Internet. Local Northern Michigan ISP, offering Dialup Internet access, Wireless access, Web design, and T1 services in Northern ...
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 
                                    [clickurl] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch_Lake_(Antrim_County,_Michigan)
                                    [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch_Lake_(Antrim_County,_Michigan)
                                    [dispurl] => en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch_Lake_(Antrim_County,_Michigan)
                                    [title] => Torch Lake (Antrim County, Michigan) - Wikipedia, the free ...
                                    [abstract] => Torch Lake at 19 miles (31 km) long is Michigan's longest lake and at approximately 18,770 acres (76 kmÂ²) is Michigan's second largest lake. Within it are several ...
                                )
```

this is the entire code that generates this array:

```
require("OAuth.php");

       $cc_key  = "";
       $cc_secret = "";
       $url = "";

       $args = array();
       $args["q"] = "car";
       $args["format"] = "json";
       $args["count"] = 20;

       $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
       $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);
       $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
       $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
       $ch = curl_init();
       $headers = array($request->to_header());
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
       $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
       $results = json_decode($rsp, true);
```

Comment: you should explain what exactly you need to do giving a simple example

Comment: from this array I have to retrieve title, abstract and url and store in mysql database

In my database I have table named text, it has 3 field: title, description and url.

In title field I need store values from title, in description field values from abstract and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information provided in the question, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
foreach($array['bossresponse']['limitedweb']['results'] as $result)
{
  echo $result['title'] . '<br />';
  echo $result['url'] . '<br />';
  echo $result['abstract'] . '<br />';
  echo '------';
}
```

Comment: Not work. Possible because it is json array?

Comment: Thanks! Now its ok, your code works great! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $your__variable["bossresponse"]["limitedweb"]["results"];
echo $res[0]["title"];
```

Create a loop to get all your properties . Escape them and store them to database.